# Julia: Scope of overloaded operators in modules

Tags: scope, operator-overloading, julia

I am trying to overload an arithmetic operator but this causes issues with other modules that use the operator. How can I limit the scope of overloads so that only the module the overload is defined in can use it. Neither lower level modules called by my module nor higher level modules that call my module should see or be affected by the operator overload.

## Minimal working example:

```
# This works as expected without overloads being declared.
a = Date(2018,1,1)
b = Date(2020,3,2)
a:Dates.Day(10):b
```

And now when an operator is overloaded there is an error as Base.range.jl uses the inbuilt definition of -(a::Date, b::Date)

```
import Base.-
function -(a::Date, b::Date)
    return (Dates.days(a) -Dates.days(b))/ 365.2422
end
a:Dates.Day(10):b
```

An obvious fix seems to be to replace `import Base.-` with `import MyPackageName.-` but this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not importing anything should do exactly what you want if I understand your problem correctly. In this case a function will be defined in your module and it will be visible only in this module. The only trick is that you use `-` inside your function definition that should use `-` from `Base`. Here is an easy fix. Put the following definitions in your module:

```
-(a,b) = Base.:-(a,b)

function -(a::Date, b::Date)
    return (Dates.days(a) -Dates.days(b))/ 365.2422
end
```

Now `-` behaves in your module as `-` in `Base` unless its both arguments are `Date` - then your own definition kicks in (but only in the module where you defined it).